# Page crashes whenever I link a CSS stylesheet on one file, but doesn't on another

Tags: css, node.js, mustache

This is my first web app which might be the issue since I'm not familiar enough with HTTP, back-end or front-end. So here's the explanation.

Whenever I try to link a certain CSS file to one of the pages (`foo.mustache`), it doesn't load at all, and throws the following error:

> *UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: invalid input syntax for integer: "style.css" . UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)*
>
> (node:4232) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

*Linking was done as usual:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">`

---

Files are organized in the Root folder in the following manner:

- **Views Folder** containing a couple of different HTML pages with Mustache templating
- **Public folder** containing main HTML and CSS stylesheets.
- **server.js** (done in Express.js)
- **package.json**

The thing that's bugging me is that the exact same stylesheet is fully operative in another HTML file (`bar.mustache`) and doesn't cause any issues but in `foo.mustache`, it wouldn't work.

I even tried putting them all in the same folder, so I wouldn't have any path issues, but still, it failed to link.

Then I quick-fixed it by copying the entire content of `style.css` and pasted in into the `<style>` tags inside `foo.mustache`, and it worked perfectly.

---

**To conclude**:
The routing, functionality and the HTML of `foo.mustache` aren't causing any issues when the CSS is not linked or the styling is placed within `<style>` tags.
As soon as I link ANY CSS to `foo.mustache`, it doesn't load at all.